What caused my pod container termination?
I am running this backend pod.
kubectl describe pods backend2-deployment-84f47d769d-6dlsr -n tutorial-application
shows
`Init Containers:
  opentelemetry-auto-instrumentation-java:
    Container ID:  containerd://2b3c4aa78111db76a42fdf506ef28690462e49fef1060d6be755dafcd90e49b3
    Image:         ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java:1.32.1
    Image ID:      ghcr.io/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-operator/autoinstrumentation-java@sha256:74662ff33c617bb635a878020492b865fa5b3a2691fb334a1ea736fb33328503
    Port:          <none>
    Host Port:     <none>
    Command:
      cp
      /javaagent.jar
      /otel-auto-instrumentation-java/javaagent.jar
    State:          Terminated
      Reason:       Completed
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Mon, 14 Oct 2024 09:11:02 +0100
      Finished:     Mon, 14 Oct 2024 09:11:03 +0100`

what does state terminted really mean? why is container terminated?
Is that expected for init container?

It means that your pod ran to completion and exited. To stay running, there must be some sort of loop, whereas the container running in your pod has simply run, and exited normally.
Edit: Just realised, that's an init container. Yes, this is perfectly normal. An Init container runs, does some stuff to intialize your pod, then exits. It must exit without error for the main containers to start

@SiHa it does not exist anymore?

what do you mean? a pod may have init container(s), they will run, then exit. This is normal

Init container called opentelemetry-auto-instrumentation is using to inject the auto-instrumentation into the app container. So exit code 0 means that it worked correctly and exited without any errors.
You can read more here about init containers. And here you can read a little bit more about opentelemetry-auto-instrumentation container.
